# Saving data from website to csv with find_all from BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to learn how to scrape a website with Python and BeautifulSoup. I have been able to collect all the names/job-titles, and I'm trying to save them into a csv-file. I either need some type of loop or append in order to get them all into a csv-file. As it stands now, only the final name and job-title are saved in the csv-file.

```
#import libraries
import csv
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#specify the url
buzzly_page = 'http://buzzlymedia.com/ourwork/'

#query the website and return the html to the variable 'page'
page = urllib2.urlopen(buzzly_page)

#parse the html
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

#query to get value of name
for name_box in soup.find_all('strong', attrs={'itemprop': 'name'}):
    name = name_box.text.strip() #remove starting and trailing
    print name

#query to get value of job-title
for job_box in soup.find_all('span', attrs={'itemprop': 'jobTitle'}):
    job = job_box.text.strip() #remove starting and trailing
    print job

#write into csv-file
with open('buzzly_clients.csv', 'a') as csv_file:
   writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
   writer.writerow([name, job])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the divs that contains the elements you want and iterate over them like this.

```
# import libraries
import csv
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# specify the url
buzzly_page = 'http://buzzlymedia.com/ourwork/'

# query the website and return the html to the variable 'page'
page = urllib2.urlopen(buzzly_page)

# parse the html
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

# write into csv-file
with open('buzzly_clients.csv', 'a') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)

    for div in soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'avia-testimonial-meta-mini'}):
        # query to get value of name
        name_box = div.find('strong', attrs={'itemprop': 'name'})
        name = name_box.text.strip()  # remove starting and trailing
        print (name)

        # query to get value of job-title
        job_box = div.find('span', attrs={'itemprop': 'jobTitle'})
        job = job_box.text.strip()  # remove starting and trailing
        print (job)

        writer.writerow([name, job])
```